# SQL Sum of aggregated values within SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple property table with an id and name field. I also have a propertyPrices table whose schema and data is shown below;

[image]

So, it specifies prices for given date ranges. The price value indicates the cost for a day within that period.

When given a start and end date, I'd like to be able to select the sum of the prices based on the number of days which fall between each date range.

I have attempted the following;

```
DECLARE @propertyID int = 1;
DECLARE @startDate date = '2014/02/13';
DECLARE @endDate date = '2014/02/18';

/* get number of days between start and end date */
DECLARE @duration int = DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate)

/* select properties with holiday cost */
SELECT 
    property.name, SUM(dbo.propertyPrices.price) * @duration AS totalCost

FROM 
    dbo.property INNER JOIN dbo.propertyPrices ON dbo.property.id = dbo.propertyPrices.propertyID

WHERE 
    property.id = @propertyID

GROUP BY 
    dbo.property.name
```

Which returns 2000 as the total cost. This is for 5 days, which is then multiplied by 400 (which is the sum of all the prices). I only want to select the appropriate price for each day in the range. So it should be;

(2 days at 100) + (3 days at 300) = 1100.

I'm not sure how I can aggregate the individual day values. My priority is performance.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Nick

Comment: i think with the parameter you are passing then it will be 2 days and not 3 days

Comment: You need to have the overlap of @@startdate and @@enddate for each record, I would go for a CASE construct to determine the number of days in overlap and the overlap should be multiplied by price (for each record). That should have a sum and that sum should be divided by duration.

Comment: Thanks AshReva, have updated question. Would you be able to provide some demonstration code please Paul?

Comment: I think your expected value is 1200 as 3*100 (13-15 feb) + 3*300 (16-18 feb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine writing a stored procedure, or the other solution would be to build up an auxiliary table just containing a list of days.

If you had a table `calendar(date)` with all dates in the affected range, you could do

```
SELECT 
    property.name, SUM(dbo.propertyPrices.price) AS totalCost

FROM 
    dbo.property
    INNER JOIN dbo.propertyPrices
        ON dbo.property.id = dbo.propertyPrices.propertyID
    JOIN calendar
        ON calendar.date between startDate and endDate

WHERE 
    property.id = @propertyID

GROUP BY 
    dbo.property.name
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks - this is the kind of simplicity I was looking for. I used an ExplodeDates table value function to join to and it works great!

Answer (score 2):

I would do it using CTEs. First get the prices with actual date ranges, then multiply price by number of days in the range and sum it.

```
with cte as
(
  select propertyID, price,
  case when startDate < @startDate then @startDate else startDate end as startDate, 
  case when endDate > @endDate then @endDate else endDate end as endDate
  from propertyPrices
  where endDate >= @startDate
  and startDate <= @endDate
)
, cte2 as
(
  select propertyID, sum((datediff(day, startDate, endDate)+1) * price) as totalCost
  from cte
  group by propertyID
)
select name, totalCost
from cte2
inner join property on id = propertyID
where id = @propertyID
```

You can view the whole solution on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af939/5/0)

Comment: Thanks for going to the lengths of creating the fiddle. I used the other solution as I couldn't use CTEs in my context.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you needed to do was add a case statement to the original query defining the conditions you wished to apply for the date boundaries and group by the start and end dates, this creates a table which you may use as a sub query to a parent select which groups by the property name.

See below code, I have used table varibales so I could test it easily, but you should be able to edit for your own table names just remove the @'s.

```
DECLARE @property AS Table(
    id INT 
,   name NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @property
SELECT 1, 'Property 1' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Property 2'


DECLARE @propertyPrices AS Table(
    id INT 
,   propertyID INT
,   startDate datetime
,   endDate datetime
,   price float
)

INSERT INTO @propertyPrices
SELECT 1, 1, '2014-02-10', '2014-02-15', 100.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, '2014-02-16', '2014-02-20', 300.00

DECLARE @propertyID int = 1;
DECLARE @startDate date = '2014/02/13';
DECLARE @endDate date = '2014/02/18';

/* get number of days between start and end date */
DECLARE @duration int = DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate)

/* select properties with holiday cost */
SELECT p.name, SUM(totalCost) FROM (
SELECT 
        p.name
    ,   CASE
            WHEN @startDate > pp.startDate AND @endDate > pp.endDate THEN 
                SUM(pp.price) * DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate)
            WHEN @endDate < pp.endDate THEN 
                SUM(pp.price) * DATEDIFF(DAY, pp.startDate, @endDate)
            ELSE 
                SUM(pp.price) * DATEDIFF(DAY, pp.startDate, pp.endDate)
        END
         AS totalCost

FROM 
    @property p INNER JOIN @propertyPrices pp ON p.id = pp.propertyID

WHERE 
    p.id = @propertyID

GROUP BY 
    p.name, pp.startDate, pp.endDate
) p GROUP BY p.name
```